# npx create-turborepo not working on my local system

Tags: next.js, monorepo, npx, turborepo

on a MacOs system when I'm trying to run npx create-turbo@latest monorepo I'm getting these errors:

TURBOREPO

Welcome to Turborepo! Let's get you set up with a new codebase.

? Which package manager do you want to use? yarn workspaces

Downloading files. This might take a moment.

> > > > Unable to download template from Github
> > > > unable to get local issuer certificate

I've tried to download cert files from its github url and put into the cert folders and keychain certs but still not working. Please could you help me?